# Help Finding Extension: Surcharge on product (M2)

Tags: magento2.4, extensions, plugin

We sell cleaning chemicals (B2B) and the state requires a VOC tax for each sale, which must be shown separately.

For accounting reasons, we are looking for a more specialised solution. Simply charging a surcharge is not an option.

The VOC taxes are clearly defined (fixed amount) and therefore we have created a separate product for each amount (own SKU, Simple, Not Visible Individually).

Now we want to link the VOC products to the cleaning chemical products:

- the VOC product must always be added to the basket with the chemical product
- the VOC product can not be removed from the shopping basket by the customer
- If the chemical product is removed from the shopping basket, the VOC product is also removed

Does anyone have a good idea how to solve this? Maybe with an extension?

Thank you very much for any help
Phil

Comment: According to specification, you need to create extension from scratch according to the requirements.